# Complete isolation in Linux sandboxing

Tags: linux, jails, sandbox

Applications on iOS (and perhaps the ones that are sandboxed on OS X) are confined to a virtual root filesystem that only has the files and directories specific to the application. The root seen by an iOS application looks like:

```
/
    Application.app/
    Documents/
    Library/
    tmp/
```

As you can see, no system executables or shared libraries are exposed in the sandbox root unlike a chroot where that would be necessary for the application to function; I think that is also the case with Tizen, bada, and many J2ME operating systems. Linux has received new technologies that can be used for sandboxing like namespaces, cgroups, seccomp-bpf which are now used in software like LXC, Docker, and Chrome OS. Can any of these technologies be used to create roots for applications that might look like:

```
/
    app/
    data/
    resources/
    app.xml
```

on an embedded platform or a consumer electronic device where someone might not want to expose the rest of the device's filesystem to applications? iOS applications, I am guessing, can make call to Apple's libraries and frameworks without having them appear in their jails, so can Linux's new technologies enable the same?

Comment: In a chroot, the system executables and shared libraries are independent from the main system. Deleting "system files" inside the chroot has no effect outside the chroot.

Comment: @StrongBad Those files have to be in the chroot for the executable to *run*.

Answer (score -1):

You don't *need* system libraries or binaries inside a `chroot` in order for an application to run.

For example:

```
$ ls chroot_test 
hello*
$ sudo chroot chroot_test /hello
Hello, World
```

Why does that work?  Because the `hello` program is statically linked and has no dependencies:

```
$ file chroot_test/hello 
chroot_test/hello: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped
```

Basically, no matter what the technology, the files that *need* to go inside the "sandbox" are the minimum necessary to run the application.  So a dynamically linked program might need `libc.so` and `ld.so` and so on.

A simple `bash` environment might need a few more files:

```
$ find chroot-bash -type f
chroot-bash/lib64/libdl.so.2
chroot-bash/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
chroot-bash/lib64/libc.so.6
chroot-bash/lib64/libtinfo.so.5
chroot-bash/bin/bash
```

We can't *do* much in it (eg no `ls` command, but it's a running `bash` shell.

```
$ sudo chroot chroot-bash /bin/bash
bash-4.2# pwd
/
bash-4.2# ls
bash: ls: command not found
bash-4.2# echo *
bin lib64
```

Note that these files are *copies* of the originals; they're not the originals (well, you *could* bind-mount them).  The OS isn't exposed.

You would need to have the same set of files in them, whether you use `chroot` or `docker` or `lxc`...

[An example of a small docker container](https://www.sweharris.org/post/2016-06-04-small-container/)

Now note that this is *also* true of the operating system itself.  When you `yum install` or `apt-get install` a package it might bring in some dependencies, including libraries!  Your OS doesn't have everything!  It just has a *bigger* set of default stuff to make it easier for people to use.

Comment: "You don't *need* system libraries or binaries inside a `chroot` in order for an application to run." Yes, I do. An executable inside of jail that calls a shared library needs to have access to it.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I didn't write clearly enough.  "Need" is a minimum necessary requirement, as explained in "the files that _need_ to go inside the sandbox are the minimum necessary to run the application".  So my "bash" sandbox needed 4 libraries and a binary.  The libraries and binaries _your_ sandbox needs are dependent on your app.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, it's more of a long comment. Sandboxing requires far more than chroot.